# CartoDb Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) error

Tags: openlayers, carto

I created a map in carto and then applied to my c# application like CartoDB source example that I saw on openlayers web page.  like this:

```
     var mapConfig = {
        'layers': [{
            'type': 'cartodb',
            'options': {
                'cartocss_version': '2.1.1',
                'cartocss': '#layer { polygon-fill: #374C70; polygon-opacity: 0.9; ::outline { line-color: #FFF; line width: 1; line-opacity: 0.5; } }',
                'sql': 'SELECT * FROM kitap1'
            }
        }]
    };

    var cartoDBSource = new ol.source.CartoDB({
        account: 'seymacengiz',
        config: mapConfig
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: cartoDBSource
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
```

At first, it was working .But now I'm getting this error:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://seymacengiz.cartodb.com/api/v1/map. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

And also this link goes to "https://carto.com/noneuser.html" 
I saw v1 in link.I think, it means version1 .

Can this be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the OpenLayers source is directing you to `cartodb.com` instead of `carto.com`. The old domain works for old accounts (but eventually we will shut down the domain also for them) but for new accounts, only the `carto.com` endpoints are going to resolve.

I don't know how the OL layer works, but maybe there's a way to force the endpoint. In the meantime I've sent an [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7216) to the OL bug tracker to fix this.

Disclaimer: I work at CARTO

Comment: In fact, I'm using free trial version now. And I signed up 2 days ago. I think it can not be old account. Thanks for issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, openlayers force to cartodb.com in their js file. I fixed this issue with changing a part of ol.js file. I created my own js file and copied ol.js to mine.I saw this code block in js file:

```
    function cx(a){var b=JSON.stringify(a.i);if(a.o[b])dx(a,a.o[b]);else{var c="https://"+a.B+".cartodb.com/api/v1/map";a.C&&(c+="/named/"+a.C);var d=new XMLHttpRequest;d.addEventListener("load",a.Pl.bind(a,b));d.addEventListener("error",a.Ol.bind(a));d.open("POST",c);d.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");d.send(JSON.stringify(a.i))}}
```

then changed cartodb.com to carto.com. I used my js file instead of ol.js. It works now thank you

Comment: It's been already fixed upstream https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/7219 so it'll be OK in the next release of Open Layers